# convert jQuery code to Polymer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

Would it be at all possible to convert some JQuery into PolymerJS?

Problem: Wanting a certain CSS class to only be applied to the element being clicked.

I had it working in JQuery, but wondering if it could be done in Polymer?
I know how to add and remove CSS from the active element, just not how to remove from all elements except the active one.

**Component being applied to**

```
 <iron-ajax id="userGet"  handle-as="json"  method="GET" on-response="setUser"></iron-ajax>
    <div class="iron-list-container">
         <iron-list id="list" items="setUser" as="user" >
            <div class="item" id="item">
                 <!-- USER INFO STUFF GOES HERE -->
             </div>
         </iron-list>
    </div>
```

[GIF of functionality I have with the JQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQxHn.gif)

**JQuery**

```
toggleLeftBorder: function() {
    $(".item").click(function() {
        $('.item').removeClass('addBorderLeft');
        $(this).addClass('addBorderLeft');
    })
},
```

**PolymerJS so far**

```
toggleLeftBorder : function() {
    /* this line will add the necessary css class to selected elements */
    this.$.item.classList.add('addBorderLeft');
},
```

Comment: Do you need to support having multiple items selected? It looks like from the jQuery snippet that would be impossible but just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: what you are looking for is basically a tutorial on how to write polymer code.. because it's pretty obvious how to convert jQuery code to vanilla, so you are asking us to teach you how to write a simple polymer code? aren't there already tutorials for that online?

Comment: @zacharytamas: I added a GIF with the current functionality I have with the JQuery that I'm wanting to reproduce.

Comment: @vsync: You may be right, but I trawled the net in search and couldn't find anything helpful earlier before I posted this question. I do, do legwork before admitting defeat.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a one-liner to do this in Polymer like jQuery provides. Polymer tries to be as light-weight as possible and doesn't add very many DOM manipulation tools.

An equivalent line in vanilla JS might be:

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('.addBorderLeft')
    .forEach(item => item.classList.remove('addBorderLeft');
```

Since you only want one item selected at a time you could just keep track of the previously selected item and remove the class from it before you set the newly selected one:

```
toggleLeftBorder : function() {
  if (this.selectedUserElement) {
    this.selectedUserElement.classList.remove('addBorderLeft');
  }

  this.selectedUserElement = this.$.item;
  this.selectedUserElement.classList.add('addBorderLeft');
},
```

**However**, since you're using `iron-list` it comes with selection baked in so you should be able to do this declaratively like this:

```
<iron-ajax id="userGet"  handle-as="json"  method="GET" on-response="setUser"></iron-ajax>

<div class="iron-list-container">
  <iron-list id="list" items="[[setUser]]" as="user" 
    selection-enabled selected-item="{{selectedUser}}">
    <div class="item">
      <!-- USER INFO STUFF GOES HERE -->
    </div>
  </iron-list>
</div>
```

This would do the following:

- Create a property on your element called `selectedUser` which is always the currently selected User. I suspect you need this elsewhere in your element/application anyway.
- Add the `selected` class to the selected `iron-list` item. Note that this is different from your `addBorderLeft` class so you'd need to put your styles on `.selected` instead.